# Batch rename files if they don't contain a character

Tags: console

I have audio files names either 'A_B.wav' or 'A.wav'. I'd like to rename all files with a filename in the format 'A.wav' to 'A_A.wav' and leave all other files unchanged.

In other words, I need to batch rename only files that contain no underscore.

Is there a way to do this via the Linux console?

Comment: You can use `find . -regex [^_]*.wav` and then chuck that into something else, such as `xargs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *;
do
    j=`echo $i | cut -d . -f 1`;
    e=`echo $i | cut -d . -f 2`;
    if [[ $j != *_* ]]
    then
        j=$j"_"$j"."$e;
        mv $i $j;
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python with standard libraries:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk
```

`Path` class will handle file parent directory, extension.
`walk` may be used to traversal path tree.

Suppose we have directory:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── dir_1
│   ├── A_1.wav
│   └── B_2.wav
├── dir_2
│   ├── C.wav
│   └── D_3.wav
├── E.wav
└── F_4.wav
```

The following bash python code does the trick:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk
list(map( lambda p: p.stem.find("_") < 0 and p.rename(p.parent/(p.stem + "_A" + p.suffix)),  sum( ( [ Path(r)/x for x in fs ] for r, _, fs in walk(".", topdown=False)), [] )) )
```

You can execute this code in directly in bash:

```bash
python3 -c 'from pathlib import Path; from os import walk; list(map( lambda p: p.stem.find("_") < 0 and p.rename(p.parent/(p.stem + "_A" + p.suffix)),  sum( ( [ Path(r)/x for x in fs ] for r, _, fs in walk(".", topdown=False)), [] )) )'
```

Now the folder looks like:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── dir_1
│   ├── A_1.wav
│   └── B_2.wav
├── dir_2
│   ├── C_A.wav
│   └── D_3.wav
├── E_A.wav
└── F_4.wav
```